# removing double quotes from a file

Tags: perl

I have a tab delimited file, that looks like this.

```
"""chr1"    "38045559"  "38046059"  "C1orf122"""
""""    ""  ""  "C1orf122"""
""""    ""  ""  "YRDC"""
"""chr1"    "205291045" "205291545" "YOD1"""
"""chr1"    "1499717"   "1500625"   "SSU72"""
```

I got this file after converting a .csv to tab separated file from this command

```
perl -lpe 's/"/""/g; s/^|$/"/g; s/","/\t/g' <test.csv>test_tab
```

Now, I want my file to remain tab separated but all the extra quotes should be removed from the file. But at the same time when I print column 4 I should get all the names and for column 1,2, and 3 the co ordinates (this I still get it but with quotes).

What manipulation shall I do in above command to do so, kindly guide.

The output desired is (since I was asked to be clear)

```
chr1    38045559    38046059    C1orf122
                                C1orf122
                                YRDC
chr1    205291045   205291545   YOD1
chr1    1499717     1500625     SSU72
```

so that when I extract Column 4 I should get

```
    C1orf122
    C1orf122
    YRDC 
    YOD1
    SSU72
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you adding quotes to the beginning and end of line if you want to remove them?

Comment: Do you understand what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that most of those quotes are being inserted by your command to bring in the file.  Instead open the file normally:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open CSV, 'test.csv' or die "can't open input file.";
open TAB, '>test.tab' or die "can't open output file.";

my @row_array;

while (<CSV>)
{
    #Remove any quotes that exist on the line (it is in default variable $_).
    s/"//g;

    #Split the current row into an array.
    my @fields = split /,/; 

    #write the output, tab-delimited file.
    print TAB join ("\t", @fields) . "\n";

    #Put the row into a multidimensional array.
    push @row_array, \@fields;
}

print "Column 4:\n";
print $_->[3] . "\n" foreach (@row_array);

print "\nColumns 1-3:\n";
print "@{$_}[0..2]\n" foreach (@row_array);
```

Any quotes that still do exist will be removed by `s/"//g;` in the above code.  This will remove *all* quotes; it doesn't check whether they are at the beginning and end of a field.  If you might have some quotes within the data that you need to preserve, you would need a more sophisticated matching pattern.

**Update:** I added code to create a tab-separated output file, since you seem to want that.  I don't understand exactly what your requirement related to getting "all the names...and the coordinates" is.  However, you should be able to use the above code for that.  Just add what you need where it says "do stuff".  You can reference, for example, column 1 with `$fields[0]`.

**Update 2:** Added code to extract column 4, then columns 1-3. The syntax for using multidimensional arrays is tricky. See [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more information.

**Update 3:** Added code to remove the quotes that still exist in your file.

Comment: Hi! first part works great, In add stuff I am trying to get rid of "foo"   "bar" these things in myfile.

Comment: @Angelo, I'm not sure what you mean.  I suggest you edit your question to show what the output should be for the sample data that you have provided.

Comment: @Angelo, now I show how to extract the columns you want.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I am unable to project my problem, I am getting closer to my answer but not to my answer. I still have my answers with quotes " ". :(

Comment: @Angelo, I have now added the code that removes quotes.  Is this what you need?